# How to achieve Before Advice pointcut for TextBox.Text spring.net AOP?

Tags: c#, asp.net, spring-aop, spring.net

I am new to Spring.NET and want to intercept TextBox.Text in ASP.NET so that value is set to the Textbox is HTMLEncoded.

My settings in web.config:

```
<configSections>
<!-- Spring for AOP-->
<sectionGroup name="spring">
  <section name="context" type="Spring.Context.Support.WebContextHandler, Spring.Web"/>
  <section name="objects" type="Spring.Context.Support.DefaultSectionHandler, Spring.Core"/>
  <section name="parsers" type="Spring.Context.Support.NamespaceParsersSectionHandler, Spring.Core"/>
</sectionGroup>
```

```
  <object id="myServiceObject" type="Spring.Aop.Framework.ProxyFactoryObject">
    <property name="target">
      <object id="myServiceObjectTarget" type="System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox"/>
    </property>
    <property name="interceptorNames">
      <list>
        <value>beforeAdvice</value>
      </list>
    </property>
  </object>
 <httpModules>
  <add name="SpringModule" type="Spring.Context.Support.WebSupportModule, Spring.Web"/>
</httpModules>
<httpHandlers>
  <add verb="*" path="*.aspx" type="Spring.Web.Support.PageHandlerFactory, Spring.Web"/>
</httpHandlers>

<system.webServer>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
<modules>
  <add name="Spring" type="Spring.Context.Support.WebSupportModule, Spring.Web"/>
</modules>
<handlers>
  <add name="SpringPageHandler" verb="*" path="*.aspx" type="Spring.Web.Support.PageHandlerFactory, Spring.Web"/>
  <add name="SpringContextMonitor" verb="*" path="ContextMonitor.ashx" type="Spring.Web.Support.ContextMonitor, Spring.Web"/>
</handlers>
```

My class implementation:

```
namespace BAY.KOL.WebSite.Aspects{

[Serializable]
public class HtmlEncodeBeforeAdvice : IMethodBeforeAdvice
{

    public void Before(MethodInfo method, Object[] args, Object target)
    {
        if (args.Length > 1 && args[0] != null)
        {
            args[0] = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(args[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

However, I am not able to achieve result. And during debug, I found the Advice Class is not called once. Am I missing something or totally on wrong track.

Comment: Are you sure the textbox is created by spring.net and not by the asp.net infrastructure. When the textbox is created by asp.net then there is no way for spring.net to exchange the textbox with a proxied textbox.

Comment: Hmm, The textbox I used is the one created by asp.net. I want to change value just before it is set to textbox. I want to apply a global solution rather than to edit code everywhere. Is there any other way to do this?